# Is (sudo) service postgresql restart a clean shutdown

Tags: postgresql

I know database indexes can become corrupted if the server crashes.  If I do:

```
sudo service postgresql restart
```

can that cause the same kind of corruption as a server crash?

Answer (score 1):

That depends on the system I belive. You should look into the script to check the actual command issued. Eg. [here](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/solrhe/Securing-Optimizing-Linux-RH-Edition-v1.3/chap27sec224.html) we see, that `restart` is equal to `stop` & `start`. then checking `stop` we see it does `killproc postmaster` and removes pid. From the man `killproc` sends `SIGTERM` if otherly not specified. By the [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/server-shutdown.html)

> SIGTERM
>
> This is the Smart Shutdown mode. After receiving SIGTERM, the
>   server disallows new connections, but lets existing sessions end their
>   work normally. It shuts down only after all of the sessions terminate.
>   If the server is in online backup mode, it additionally waits until
>   online backup mode is no longer active. While backup mode is active,
>   new connections will still be allowed, but only to superusers (this
>   exception allows a superuser to connect to terminate online backup
>   mode). If the server is in recovery when a smart shutdown is
>   requested, recovery and streaming replication will be stopped only
>   after all regular sessions have terminated.

So in presented case, indexes should survive. But you definetely should watch your `/etc/init.d/` script to be sure.